# Replace the backslash with space in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
k = "hello'S";
var sym = k.replace(/\'/g,"\\'");
```

I want my output to look like: hello's

I am getting it now as hello\'s

Comment: output is `hello'S` without any logic. see: `console.log("hello\'S");`

Comment: This doesn't make sense  `"hello\'S"` produces the string `hello'S`, i.e. exactly what you want. You have to understand that ``\`` is the escape character in string literals and as such it is *not* contained literally in the string value.

Answer (score 2):

From your comment (with various typos fixed):

> ```
> var k = "hello's";
> var sym =k.replace(/\'/g,'\\\'');
> onclick = "gosymbol(\''+k+'\',event);
> ```
>
> by doing this i am getting output as hello\'s but i wanted it to be like hello's

So what you're trying to do is embed a string in an `onclick` handler as text. That's not a good idea, not least because of the quoting hassles. Instead:

```
someElement.onclick = gosymbol.bind(someElement, k);
```

**Live Example:**

```js
var k = "hello's";
var someElement = document.getElementById("some-element");
someElement.onclick = gosymbol.bind(someElement, k);

function gosymbol(arg, e) {
  alert("gosymbol got: [" + arg + "], event type: " + e.type);
}
```

```html
<div id="some-element">Click me</div>
```

If for some reason it **has** to be a string, then the problem is that you didn't have the right number of `'` characters in your `onclick` line, and had `k` **in** the string literally (which means you weren't getting the output you described), and weren't using `sym`:

```
var k = "hello's";
var sym = k.replace(/'/g, "\\'");
onclick = "gosymbol('" + sym + "',event);";
```

**I do not suggest doing that,** but if that's what you want to do...

**Live Example:**

```js
var someElement = document.getElementById("some-element");
var k = "hello's";
var sym = k.replace(/'/g, "\\'");
someElement.setAttribute("onclick", "gosymbol('" + sym + "',event);");

function gosymbol(arg, e) {
  alert("gosymbol got: [" + arg + "], event type: " + e.type);
}
```

```html
<div id="some-element">Click me</div>
```

Comment: var k = hello's var sym =k.replace(/\'/g,'\\\'');  onlick = "gosymbol(\''+k+'\',event) by doing this i am getting output as hello\'s but i wanted it to be like hello's

Comment: @user2916626: Look at the code in the answer, then look at your code in the comment above.

Comment: @user2916626: Your question says you want to *remove* the backslash. Your code above looks like you're trying to *add* one.

Comment: I want to add it first and then remove it later

Comment: @user2916626: I've taken a guess at what you're really trying to do and updated the answer.